# Redo shortened multiplication for loop code

Tags: java

My homework objective is to code a 10x10 multiplication made of for loops. This was the intended output.

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20
3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30
4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

To create this code, I used 2 variables (i and j) and multiplied them for each number in the table. However, my computer science teacher told me that while my code could work alright, the optimal code I needed was one line shorter. I needed to condense the second for loop with the print function that followed such.

```
public class inputOutputExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++){
            for (int j=1; j<=10;j++){
                System.out.print(j*i + "\t"); 
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

For clarification the code lines:

```
for (int j=1; j<=10;j++){
    System.out.print(j*i + "\t");
}
```

are the ones that should be "reduced to 1 print statement". Can someone explain what that means or provide an example? Thank you!

Comment: *"one line shorter"* Then remove `Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);`. You're not using `in` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need second loop as you know that you just need to multiply i with 1 to 10.

```
public class Multiplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d%n",
                    i * 1, i * 2, i * 3, i * 4, i * 5, i * 6, i * 7, i * 8, i * 9, i * 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` ?

Comment: removed the scanner